Why is my appendix not properly numbered?
I am using a template with a customized document class (that I have to use) and I want to use and appendix. I used:
\backmatter
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}
\section{Appendix A.1}
\section{Appendix A.2}

In my table of contents, everything until the appendix works fine (chapters are numbered 1,2,3..., sections are numbered 1.1,1.2,... and so forth), however in the Appendix only the text of appears without numbering. I would like to the Chapter appendix to be "A" and then the sections in the appendix to be numbered A.1, A.2 and so forth. I am not sure if this is possible with that specific document class.
Is there a command available that accomplishes this?

As we do not knwo youur setup (class and preamble), please provide a full but minimal exmaple others can copy and test as is. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In most classes I know, \backmatter deactivates the numbering of chapters. So try removing \backmatter.

Thank you, removing \backmatter did the trick.
